# reduce number of points of a geometry of sf object in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am facing the following problem:

when using the shape file of intercommunal limits in France (which you can download here: https://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/datasets/r/971027a8-3ceb-48c6-97e3-59deaf7e2704), plotting the map is really slow:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

epci_france <- read_sf("./epci_shape/EPCI_SHAPEFILE.shp")

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = test,
          aes(geometry = geometry),
          color = "black")+
  guides(fill = "none")+
  theme_void()
```

I think this is due to the high number of points in the shapefile.

Following comments in here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2655, I tried

```
sum(rapply(st_geometry(epci_france), nrow))
[1] 1913182
```

which looks like a lot of points. I am looking for a way to lower this number, i.e. lower the precision of the limits of the geometry. I tried `smooth` from `library(smoothr)`, but it has the opposite effect: it increases the number of points. I tried to cast it to other formats with `st_cast`, but it did not work either.

How should I proceed? My objective is to have a simple delimitation of the intercommunal limits to make choropleth maps. Thanks!

Comment: have a look at `library(rmapshaper)` and the function `ms_simplify()`

Comment: @SymbolixAU thanks, it went from 1913182 to 110470, it is perfect.

Comment: You can also take a look at `st_simplify` in the same `sf` package.